# Reconstructing From Conditionals

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

Let $X_t=f(Y_t,Z_t)$ be a stochastic process depending on $Y_t$ and on $Z_t$; all of which are Markovian.  If I know $g,h$ where
$$
E[X_t|Y_t]=h(Z_t,Y_t),
$$
and 
$$
E[X_t|Z_t]=g(Z_t,Y_t)
$$
then can I determine what $X_t$ is at time $t$?

Comment: Hmm... so $h(Z_t)$ is $Y_t$-measurable and $g(Y_t)$ is $Z_t$-measurable?  That is a lot to ask for $(Y_t,Z_t)$, $h$ and $g$.

Comment: Oops, fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

Let $Y,Z$ be independent copies of the two state symmetric Markov chain starting with the invariant distribution.  Let $X=1_{Y=Z}-1_{Y\neq Z}$.  It is easy to check
$$
\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Z]=0, 
$$
but of course $X\neq 0$.

Comment: True!  Great example